# Fix layout / plot options of plot(fevd()) function

Tags: r, variables, plot

I am currently busy with a Vector Autoregressive Analysis in R, using the vars package. I was wondering if the following things are possible:

1) the previous solution for a better fit on the page worked properly, but now with more variables, we have more plots and the layout is screwed again. I already played with some of the win.graph() parameters, but nothing gives me a proper readable solution.

2) The plot(irf(...) function of the vars package gives a one-graph per page output. I was wondering if this is also possible for the plot(fevd() function by adding some extra (unkown to me) parameters  options

3) Also, for readability, I would like to color the graphs, plot(fevd() gives an all-kinds-of-gray output, Is it possible to change those colors?

[image: my current output]

Thank you in advance

Olivier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to modify the plot function for fevd to do what you want. Here's a modified `plot.varfevd` function that removes all calls to `par()`. This allows to use `layout` properly. The lines that have been removed have been commented out (#). I also removed the parameter that asked for confirmation in "single" plots.

```
plot.varfevd  <-function (x, plot.type = c("multiple", "single"), names = NULL,
    main = NULL, col = NULL, ylim = NULL, ylab = NULL, xlab = NULL,
    legend = NULL, names.arg = NULL, nc, mar = par("mar"), oma = par("oma"),
    addbars = 1, ...)
{
    K <- length(x)
    ynames <- names(x)
    plot.type <- match.arg(plot.type)
    if (is.null(names)) {
        names <- ynames
    }
    else {
        names <- as.character(names)
        if (!(all(names %in% ynames))) {
            warning("\nInvalid variable name(s) supplied, using first variable.\n")
            names <- ynames[1]
        }
    }
    nv <- length(names)
#    op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
    ifelse(is.null(main), main <- paste("FEVD for", names), main <- rep(main,
        nv)[1:nv])
    ifelse(is.null(col), col <- gray.colors(K), col <- rep(col,
        K)[1:K])
    ifelse(is.null(ylab), ylab <- rep("Percentage", nv), ylab <- rep(ylab,
        nv)[1:nv])
    ifelse(is.null(xlab), xlab <- rep("Horizon", nv), xlab <- rep(xlab,
        nv)[1:nv])
    ifelse(is.null(ylim), ylim <- c(0, 1), ylim <- ylim)
    ifelse(is.null(legend), legend <- ynames, legend <- legend)
    if (is.null(names.arg))
        names.arg <- c(paste(1:nrow(x[[1]])), rep(NA, addbars))
    plotfevd <- function(x, main, col, ylab, xlab, names.arg,
        ylim, ...) {
        addbars <- as.integer(addbars)
        if (addbars > 0) {
            hmat <- matrix(0, nrow = K, ncol = addbars)
            xvalue <- cbind(t(x), hmat)
            barplot(xvalue, main = main, col = col, ylab = ylab,
                xlab = xlab, names.arg = names.arg, ylim = ylim,
                legend.text = legend, ...)
            abline(h = 0)
        }
        else {
            xvalue <- t(x)
            barplot(xvalue, main = main, col = col, ylab = ylab,
                xlab = xlab, names.arg = names.arg, ylim = ylim,
                ...)
            abline(h = 0)
        }
    }
    if (plot.type == "single") {
#        par(mar = mar, oma = oma)
#        if (nv > 1)
#            par(ask = TRUE)
        for (i in 1:nv) {
            plotfevd(x = x[[names[i]]], main = main[i], col = col,
                ylab = ylab[i], xlab = xlab[i], names.arg = names.arg,
                ylim = ylim, ...)
        }
    }
    else if (plot.type == "multiple") {
        if (missing(nc)) {
            nc <- ifelse(nv > 4, 2, 1)
        }
        nr <- ceiling(nv/nc)
        par(mfcol = c(nr, nc), mar = mar, oma = oma)
        for (i in 1:nv) {
            plotfevd(x = x[[names[i]]], main = main[i], col = col,
                ylab = ylab[i], xlab = xlab[i], names.arg = names.arg,
                ylim = ylim, ...)
        }
    }
#    on.exit(par(op))
}
```

Then, you will need short variable names. Pick acronyms if needed.

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
colnames(Canada) <-c("name1","name2","name3","name4")
var <- VAR(Canada , p=4 , type = "both")
```

Using a wide plot window (using `win.graph`) and using `layout` (to get the placement of your eight plots), you can get all charts displayed properly. I also changed the colors of the plots as requested. Finally, we are now using `single` plots as there are no calls to `par()` which do not sit well with `layout()`.

```
win.graph(width=15,height=8)
layout(matrix(1:8,ncol=2))
plot.varfevd(fevd(var, n.ahead = 10 ),plot.type = "single", col=1:4)
plot.varfevd(fevd(var, n.ahead = 10 ),plot.type = "single", col=1:4)
```

[image]